# Cancel one request in ASINetworkQueue

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to cancel a particular request in asinetworkqueue?

Answer (score 1):

`[queue operations];` will return an `NSArray` of items in the queue, which you can then iterate and call `cancel` on any request you like.

Something like:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in [queue operations])
{
    if (shouldCancel(req))
        [req cancel];
}
```

Comment: Thanks....But it is not working for me..Would you tell me where i am going wrong..Here is my code: for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in [networkQueue operations])
 {
  if([[req requestID] intValue]==2)
  {
     [req cancel];
  }
  }

Comment: Why isnt it working? U will get all the requests in the array. When you get the request u want cancel it

Comment: I want to cancel the request based on its request Id but i am unable to cancel i dont know where am i getting wrong...

Comment: NSLog and see if the request with id 2 is present.

Comment: ya..i checked its there but while trying to cancel that request all the request in that queue is getting cancelled....

Comment: check the requestid for all requests.

Comment: i enqueued only 3 request and i am getting both the request with requestid 1,2 and 3,but i am unable to cancel the request in that queue.

Comment: Not sure about this, but I think you need to set the [queue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO] property. If a request is cancelled, it is treated as "failed" as far as I know. So that might do the job for you.